# Trying to trigger an animation when colliding with a bullet

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Well, I'm trying to make an fps where you shoot tagets and appears an "Arcade-Style" score over them on unity 5, but, I don´t really know how to do it, already tried with an `OnCollisionEnter()`, but I did something wrong and it didn't worked, What can I do? Below you can see my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Diana : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject diana;
    public AnimationClip Score;

    private Animation myAnimation;

    /* IEnumerator Wait()
    {

        myAnimation = GetComponent<Animation>();
        myAnimation.Play("DianaScore");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);

    } */

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        Debug.Log("Funcó wacho");
        myAnimation = GetComponent<Animation>();
        myAnimation.Play("DianaScore");
       // StartCoroutine(Wait());
    }
    void Update () {

   }
}
```

(Sorry for my bad english, I´m argentinian and new in all this coding thing)

Comment: This kind of question may work on the unity forums, but it wont work here. SO questions are expected to have a minimum quality and an actual problem. You can read more about them in the help [ask], maybe you can show what you have tried, and what is not working

Comment: I´m sorry, just entered here by a question about something similar, and tought someone could help me.

Comment: No need to be sorry, just edit with what you have tried, and the code you have

Comment: Does the Console Message appear when you hit an Enemy? Where is the Script located on the Target on the Player or on the Bullet? Are you sure you enabled IsTrigger on that component?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest putting this line of code: myAnimation = GetComponent(); into a Awake() function. If the above method does not work, I suggest checking that the Is Trigger is checked for OnTriggerEnter. If the console message (Debug.Log) shows, the problem might be something to do to the animation not the script. Last but not least, check that the bullet actually collides. I know this might sound crazy, but sometimes the bullet might be able to "not get detected" if it has enough velocity. Hope these suggestions work :D .

Comment: I´ll try.
the debug message appears, also I´ll check if the bullet collides or not, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, if the Debug.Log message appears try checking that the animation has no problems.